# return count of record collection

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I am fairly new to apex and SOQL. I am trying to get a record count of a new collection list to display in VF. any hints?

```java
Public with sharing class TestDisplayQueryList2 {
    public List<LeadHistory> ResultList2
    {
        get
        {
            List<LeadHistory> leadHistoryList = new List<LeadHistory>();
            for (LeadHistory lh : [SELECT NewValue,Id, LeadId, CreatedDate FROM LeadHistory Where Field='Status' LIMIT 50000])
            {
                if(lh.NewValue == 'Convert')
                    leadHistoryList.add(lh);
            
            }
            return leadHistoryList;
        }
    }
    
    public List<AggregateResult> ResultList3
    {
        get
        {
            List<AggregateResult> results2 = [SELECT COUNT (id) cnt FROM LeadHistory];
            return results2;
        }
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: `results2.size()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
String QueryString = 
'SELECT count() FROM Account'; 
Integer i = Database.countQuery(QueryString);
```

you could try this

Comment: There's no reason to make the query dynamic here.

Answer (score -2):

results2[0].get('cnt') will return the number of records.

Comment: `results2` is a `List<AggregateResult>`, not a single `AggregateResult`, so this would generate an error as-is. While it appears that the `COUNT(Id)` without a `GROUP BY` does return the count of records, `results2.size()` (without the `COUNT(Id)` in the query) would accomplish the same thing with less typing. The one benefit I can see to using `COUNT(Id)` here is that it only counts as 1 row against the query row governor limit.

Comment: ok right  @Derek F so this will work then results2[0].get('cnt'), as he used an alias for the count, or I did not understand what is the question maybe.